# Do I need to do any extra work when publishing an app in Google Play Store which uses firebase/firestore service?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-play-console

I have published several normal apps in Google Play Store which do not use firebase/firestore service. Now, I am going to publish an app which uses firebase/firestore service.

In some places I have seen some people using SHA-1 when publishing an app having firebase/firestore service, but I am confused about it.

Do I need to do any extra work when publishing an app which uses firebase/firestore service?
(my app uses Firebase Authentication)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are signing your published apps with Google Play then add the **newly generated SHA-1 in Release>App Signing>App signing key certificate** to the **project setting on firebase**.

Otherwise, No extra work needed as long as you have setup your firebase project correctly.

Comment: In some websites I saw people using SHA-1 code when publishing an app having firebase service. Now, I am confused. Do you have any practical experience? @SABANTO

Comment: Sha-1 is only for phone auth and Google sigin if I'm not mistaken

Comment: My app uses **Firebase Authentication**. @Jason

Comment: I meant phone authentication and Google authentication on Firebase authentication

Comment: @RAWNAKYAZDANI I have published apps on Google Play using Firebase. By Firebase Authentication what do you mean exactly, there are several authentication methods, email, Facebook, Google etc.

Comment: @Jason you might be right, I'm not sure.

Comment: @SABANTO I have understood the point. Accept my edit suggestion and I will accept your answer.